# How to use the Visual Studio Team Services API

Tags: c#, json, azure-devops

I've cracked how to pull data using the API but now I'm trying to push a new work item to a project and i just can't seem to get it working here's my c# :

```
  try {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
             ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", token))));

        string Url = $"https://XXX/DefaultCollection/{Job.Project}/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=1.0";
        var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, Url) {
               Content = new StringContent(Job.WorkItem, Encoding.UTF8,
                            "application/json-patch+json")
                    };

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result) {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;                        
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                return null;
            }
```

Here is Job.WorkItem as shown up in the debugger

```
"[
    {
        \"op\":\"add\",
        \"path\":\"/fields/System.Title\",
        \"value\":\"Please add a business area for XXX Systems\\n\"
    }
]"
```

Have I missed something or doing something wrong as it responds with

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-TFS-ProcessId: xxx
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS,GET,POST,PATCH,PUT,DELETE
  Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ActivityId,X-TFS-Session,X-MS-ContinuationToken
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
  X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
  X-VSS-UserData: xxxx
  ActivityId: xxxx
  X-TFS-Session: xxx
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Wed, 13 Jul 2016 16:48:28 GMT
  P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR ADMa DEV CONo TELo CUR PSA PSD TAI IVDo OUR SAMi BUS DEM NAV STA UNI COM INT PHY ONL FIN PUR LOC CNT"
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 429
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

I have omitted some details with xxx just FYI

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to REST [Api documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items) for specific actions.

Also, as you are calling it from .net maybe [client lib](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet) for VSO Api is a simpler way to go?

Comment: ill look into the client lib, I was using the API docs and I thought I'd done everything correctly

Answer (score 0):

There is redundant double quotation marks in the Job.WorkItem which will cause bad request. The content should be:

```
[
    {
        \"op\":\"add\",
        \"path\":\"/fields/System.Title\",
        \"value\":\"Please add a business area for XXX Systems\\n\"
    }
]
```

Refer to this link for details: [Create a work item](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#create-a-work-item).